# Can I specify which host directory to mount when deploying an app using Spring Cloud Deployer Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an app that I deploy as part of a stream with Spring Cloud Dataflow on a Kubernetes cluster. The Docker image for the app contains a `VOLUME` instruction and I'd like to specify a directory on the host to mount the volume to. (This is network-attached storage that all hosts in the cluster can access.)

I didn't see anything in [`KubernetesDeployerProperties`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/KubernetesDeployerProperties.java).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no built-in support for volumes. Feel free to raise an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues

Comment: This is implemented in the latest release: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/85